# Configure Network adapter in Windows to connect to RPi

Tags: networking, ssh, windows

I have the following issue:
I'm not able to connect via SSH (using puTTY) to my RPi. The problem is about the IP configuration that i don't know exactly what it is.

At my PC with Windows XP (with Internet connection) i have two network adapters. One is connected to the LAN which provides me the Internet connection, this adapter marked as "Local Area Network 3". The another network adapter is connected to the RPi, this network adapter is marked as "Local Area Network 2".

I have no problem connecting to my RPi at another PC with openSUSE Linux installed, even if i don't know the Rpi's IP i use nmap to discover it.

I ran nmap but i can't discover the RPi's.

So, what it is the correct configuration in Windows in order to connect to my RPi? How can i get the RPi's IP?

Comment: How "Local Area Network 2" adapter connected to Pi? Cross-over  or via switch/router? Why Windows PC has 2 adapters?

Comment: Local Area Network 2 adapter is connected by a cross-over cable to the RPi. The another adapter maybe is connected to a router, i don't have access to it. I Just plug the ethernet cable to "Local Area Network 3" to get Internet and office LAN access.

Comment: I don't know why this PC have two network adapters, (one was disabled by default) but i think is useful if I don't have physical access to the router or i don't  have one, and want to keep my Internet access without disconnecting my RPi since i don't have a wireless adapter for it.

Answer (score 1):

On the Raspberry Pi, run `cat /etc/network/interfaces | grep -i address`.

If that doesn't return anything, then try `cat /var/lib/dhc*/dhclient.leases` and see what you get.

Then, you can use the Local IP you just found to connect to the Pi via PuTTY, or anything else.